# the number of $n\times n$ matrices of 0's and 1's such that every row and column has three 1's

Tags: combinatorics

In the Example 1.1.3 of Stanley's book Enumerative Combinatorics Vol 1 (2nd edition), an explicit formula for the number $f(n)$ of $n\times n$ matrices of $0$'s and $1$'s such that every row and column has three $1$'s is presented:

> $$f(n)=6^{-n}n!^2\sum\frac{(-1)^\beta(\beta+3\gamma)!\,2^\alpha\,3^\beta}{\alpha!\,\beta!\,\gamma!^2\,6^\gamma}\;,$$
>
> where the sum ranges over all $(n+2)(n+1)2$ solutions to $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=n$ in nonnegative integers.

But, I would like to know how we can prove it? It seems that inclusion-exclusion principle is used.